# Tx Rx pins not working correctly

Tags: raspbian

Today I was working with raspberrypi the tx rx pins were working fine. 5v Relay module was connected to raspberrypi and its signal wire connected with tx pin of raspberrypi so as to start 16X2 LCD as soon as raspberrypi turns on (as tx pin of raspberrypi gets high when it starts).
But now Tx pin of raspberrypi is continuously high.
I think problem is that I have connected 7v to power raspberrypi via GPIO.
Can raspberrypi pi Tx Rx got damaged due to this. If yes then how only Tx and Rx pins got damaged not everything also.

MY RASPBERRY PI IS WORKING FINE EXCEPT TX RX PINS.

Comment: Possible cause if the tx/rx pins were connected to something is they had a path to ground, whereas disconnected pins would not.

Comment: **You need to clearly explain what you connected to what**. Feeding more than 3V3 into a GPIO or more than 6V into the Pi 5V supply will eventually destroy the Pi.

Comment: I have an XL6009 module (boost converter) that is connected to TP4056 and lipo cell. This setup was to power the pi. But I was noticing that when output of XL6009 was 5v and I connect it to raspberrypi then module's voltage drops suddenly to 2-3v . So I decided to increase module's voltage to around 7-8v so that when i connect it to raspberrpi its voltage goes to 5v. So that was the situation. :( So what's wrong I have done ?

Comment: @KushagraBehere you need a stable voltage controlled power supply for the Pi.